# Restarting nginx&gunicorn without sudo

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, python, django, fabric

Can I run `systemctl restart gunicorn && systemctl restart nginx` without `sudo`? Currently I get:

> out: Authentication is required to reload 'gunicorn.service'.
>
> out: Authenticating as: myuser
>
> out: Password:

```
# coding: utf-8
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.colors import green, red


def production():
    env.host_string = '159.xxx.xxx.xx'
    env.user = 'myuser'
    path = "/home/myuser/myproject/myproject"
    print(red("Beginning Deploy:"))
    with cd(path):
        with prefix('. /home/myuser/myproject/myenv/bin/activate'):
            run("pwd")
            print(green("Pulling master from git..."))
            run("git pull")
            print(green("Migrate the database..."))
            run("python3 manage.py migrate")
            print(green("Restart the uwsgi process"))
            run("systemctl restart gunicorn && systemctl restart nginx")
        print(red("DONE!"))
```

Comment: Could you provide details on where this configuration file is from?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a PolicyKit rule to allow for restarting units without authentication.

For example this will allow any user to restart the named services (may need a bit of tweaking):

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (action.id == "org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units") {
        polkit.log("action=" + action)
        polkit.log("subject=" + subject)
        polkit.log("unit="+action.lookup("unit"))
        polkit.log("verb="+action.lookup("verb"))
        if (action.lookup("unit") == "gunicorn.service" ||
            action.lookup("unit") == "nginx.service") {
            var verb = action.lookup("verb");
            if (verb == "start" || verb == "restart") {
                polkit.log("returning YES")
                return polkit.Result.YES;
            }
        }
    }
    polkit.log("returning NO")
});
```

Place your rules in a file in the `/etc/polkit-1/rules.d` directory, with a filename ending in `.rules`.

This requires systemd 226 or higher, which in Ubuntu means 16.04 LTS or later.

(And if you think that looks like JavaScript, that's because *it is JavaScript*.)

You can also limit it to specific users by checking `subject.user`, e.g.:

```
if (subject.user == "deploy" || subject.user == "me") {
```